# Ruby undefined variables in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a view which looks like this:

```
<p><%= stage.end_date.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y")%></p>
```

Sometimes stage.end_date returns null and that's ok, but Ruby throws a NoMethodError.

I'm quite new to Ruby so I want to know how I should I deal with missing/null varibles in views

- Do I need to test for stage.end_date in the view? because that feels ugly
- Do I need to make sure
  that stage.end_date isn't null, if so
  that isn't a job for my view is it?
- Is there a way I can get ruby not
  worry out about stage.end_date and
  not throw an errow?

Advice most welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this a bunch of ways, but here are two:

```
<p><%= stage.end_date.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y") unless stage.end_date.nil? %></p>
```

or in your stage model, create:

```
def end_date_formatted
  return "" if end_date.nil?
  end_date.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y")
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use the Rails method try.  Essentially do this:

```
stage.end_date.try(:strftime,"%A, %d %B %Y")
```

When end_date is nil, try will not call the method, and just return nil.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is calling strftime on a nil object.  Here is an irb example:

```
>> t = Time.now
=> Thu Jul 22 16:52:10 -0400 2010
>> x = nil
=> nil
>> puts t.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y")
Thursday, 22 July 2010
=> nil
>> puts x.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y")
NoMethodError: undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):4
```

When you call a method (like strftime) on an object that may be nil, you will get this error.  You can try the following for those cases:

```
<p><%= stage.end_date.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y") unless stage.end_date.nil? %></p>
```

if that doesn't work, replace `.nil?` for `.blank?`

Hope that helps.